# expected primary-expression befor ')' in a function call

Tags: c++

```
struct nodeeval {       //node definition for post fix expression evaluation
    double data;
    nodeeval * next;
};


void push(T* &  top, T item) {
    T * p;
    p = new T;
    if (p!=NULL) {
        p->data = item;
        p->next = top;
        top = p;
    }
}
push((&nodeeval), ((double)cur));
```

This code generates the error(expected primary-expression befor ')', y is it i couldn't figure out.help?

Answer (score 2):

```
push((&nodeeval), ((double)cur));
```

`nodeeval` is a type here. Pass the variable that points to `top`.

For example:

```
nodeval *top = 0;
push<nodeval>(top, ((double)cur));
push<nodeval>(top, ((double)pi));
```

Comment: i did what u said and there is an other error poping all over the place.

Comment: no match function for  call to push(nodepost**,char&)

Comment: also no match function for call to push(nodeval**,char&) is generated?

Comment: How did you templatized the function `push`

Comment: @tbj Make the second parameter of function `push` templatized or `double` as shown @ http://ideone.com/V7FU5x

Comment: im traying to write the code to change infix to postfix. and this is what i did so far.

Comment: @tbj Why in the world do you want the templatized push and pop?